# UIImage.FromData() returning null

Tags: null, uiimage, touch, byte, mvvmcross

I'm building an plugin for my Mvvmcross app. For this plugin, I want to have something like:

```
myPlugin.ShowImage(imageBytes);
```

And then in my plugin, i'll do:

```
public void ShowImage(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        var parameterBundle = new MvxBundle((new MvxDisplayImageViewModel.Nav
        {
            imageBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString (imageBytes)
        }.ToSimplePropertyDictionary()));

        var mvxViewModelRequest = new MvxViewModelRequest (typeof(MvxDisplayImageViewModel), parameterBundle, null, null);
        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher> ().ShowViewModel (mvxViewModelRequest);
    }
```

So far, I have everything working, but then inside my ViewModel and View i have:

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class MvxDisplayImageViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private byte[] _imageBytes;
    public byte[] ImageBytes 
    {
        get
        { 
            return _imageBytes;
        }
        set
        {
            _imageBytes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => ImageBytes);
        }
    }

    public class Nav
    {
        public string imageBytes { get; set; }
    }

    public void Init(Nav navigation)
    {
        ImageBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (navigation.imageBytes);
    }

    public MvxDisplayImageViewModel ()
    {
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public partial class MvxDisplayImageViewController : MvxViewController
{
    protected new MvxDisplayImageViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return base.ViewModel as MvxDisplayImageViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public MvxDisplayImageViewController () : base ("MvxDisplayImageViewController", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        Title = ViewModel.ImageName;

        UIImage image = null;
        try 
        {
            using(var imageNsData = NSData.FromArray(ViewModel.ImageBytes))
            {
                image = new UIImage(imageNsData);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //image = invalid image...
        }
        finally
        {
            imageView.Image = image;
        }
    }
}
```

but then, it is not showing the image, for some reason:

I'm receiving the following exception in catch:

```
 Message:
    Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithData:' method returned nil. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.


Stacktrace:   
    at Foundation.NSObject.InitializeHandle (IntPtr handle, System.String initSelector) [0x000b0] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/maccore/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:468 
    at UIKit.UIImage..ctor (Foundation.NSData data) [0x00027] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/build/native/UIKit/UIImage.g.cs:108 
    at MyPlugin.Multimedia.Touch.MvxDisplayImageViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x0002e] in /Users/gbastos/Documents/Gabriel Docs/Development/Plugins/MyPlugin/MyPlugin.Touch/ShowImage/MvxDisplayImageViewController.cs:43
```

Comment: Use image = UIImage.LoadFromData(imageNsData)

Comment: Can you share the code of how you convert image to byte array? Because I use this code in my app, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: To get the image, I use something as simple as that:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Touch/MvxImagePickerTask.cs

Just posted the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this code is working fine. That's how it should be done.

My problem was when passing the bytes to the view inside the bundle. I was trying accomplish this with:

```
UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString (imageBytes)
```

and this:

```
UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (navigation.imageBytes);
```

But this way, does not work. I realized that because the length of the bytes were not the same. So, I changed to this (that is working now):

```
Convert.ToBase64String (image.Data)
```

and

```
Convert.FromBase64String (navigation.imageBytes)
```

Comment: Told ya there has to be something wrong with the data ;) Good that you got the solution.